# How to redirect everything to 404 not found?

Tags: redirection

I need to block an entire Drupal 7 site from being indexed for a while. So, I think it is best to redirect everything to 404 instead of actually deleting all my files. How can I do that?

PS: using the following code on .htaccess does not seem to work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

**-- Update 03/04/2015 --** 
The server is nginx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are just trying to keep it from being indexed, you can just add

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

To the top of your robots.txt

Comment: This is one of a good option to use for being indexed, but I really need the 404. :(

Comment: since the nginx does not support .htaccess, I'm going to mark this as my answer. Ty @Patrick Ryan

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to remove the existing Drupal rewrites for the moment; with them left in the .th access this code won't work.

Comment: I dont have anything in ".htaccess" beside those 2 lines of code.

Comment: I updated the question. The site is running on nginx, not sure does it really matter.

Comment: If the server is nginx .htaccess has no effect.